# Google AppEngine development server arguments

Tags: eclipse, gwt

In the Eclipse Run Configurations for Google Web Applications, I see a list of program arguments, like this:

> -remoteUI "${gwt_remote_ui_server_port}:${unique_id}" -startupUrl Test_AppEngine.html -logLevel INFO -codeServerPort 9997 -port 8888 ...

Two questions:  1) where is "gwt_remote_ui_server_port" and"unique_id" defined, and more generally, 2) where can I find a description of all the possible arguments here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List of arguments to be passed in hostedmode and compile mode for GWT compiler - https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCompilingAndDebugging

The arguments `-remoteUI "${gwt_remote_ui_server_port}:${unique_id}"` are not related to GAE instead they are related to GWT Hosted Mode being launched in **Eclipse's Devlopment Mode view** instead of stand alone app outside eclipse.

[image]

If you remove the arguments `-remoteUI "${gwt_remote_ui_server_port}:${unique_id}"`, GPE will still launch. This time as stand alone app.

[image]